# Padding style applied to element doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I try to add bottom-space to my `email_info` element, but it doesn't work

```css
div#email_info {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 650px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="verificationInfoText" id="email_info" style="display: inline;" aria- hidden="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite">Un code de validation a été envoyé à votre adresse courriel. Veuillez l'inscrire ci-dessous.
  </div>
</div>
<label id="email_label" for="email">Adresse courriel</label>
```

Comment: You want padding on an inline element?

Comment: @epascarello It would be more helpful to explain that vertical padding doesn't work on inline elements.

Comment: just remove `display: inline` and it fixes itself.

Comment: @Sean Well it does work, just not how OP is expecting. Really unclear what is expected result.

Comment: yes. I need a space between the div and label without changing the label css style.

Comment: So why is it inline?

Comment: This is an injected code from azure b2c, and I need to customize the style css.

Comment: @epascarello that's my mistake sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inline elements, although horizontal padding and margins are respected, their vertical counterparts are ignored, so `padding-bottom` doesn't work here because you're forcing your `<div>` to be inline with `style="display: inline;"`.
Just remove that to solve your issue.

```css
div#email_info {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 650px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="verificationInfoText" id="email_info" aria-hidden="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite">Un code de validation a été envoyé à votre adresse courriel. Veuillez l'inscrire ci-dessous.
  </div>
</div>
<label id="email_label" for="email">Adresse courriel</label>
```

Alternatively, you could apply the padding to the other `<div>` instead, which isn't declared as inline, and that should work too.

```css
div.container {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
div#email_info {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="verificationInfoText" id="email_info" style="display: inline;" aria-hidden="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite">Un code de validation a été envoyé à votre adresse courriel. Veuillez l'inscrire ci-dessous.
  </div>
</div>
<label id="email_label" for="email">Adresse courriel</label>
```

Comment: Also see this useful link provided by j08691 in their answer: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/

Answer (score 1):

Vertical padding [doesn't apply](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/) to an `inline` element. Change it to `inline-block` instead.

```css
div#email_info {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 650px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="verificationInfoText" id="email_info" style="display: inline-block;;" aria- hidden="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite">Un code de validation a été envoyé à votre adresse courriel. Veuillez l'inscrire ci-dessous.
  </div>
</div>
<label id="email_label" for="email">Adresse courriel</label>
```